# C functions produce segmentation fault in 64-bit code

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to compile the following 64-bit code in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS):

```
global start

extern scanf, printf, exit

section .data
    read_name db '%255s', 0
    msg db 'Hello, %s', 0Ah, 0

section .text
start:
    sub rsp, 256
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov rdi, read_name
    call scanf
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov rdi, msg
    call printf
    add rsp, 256
    xor rdi, rdi
    call exit
```

This is how I compile my code:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello64.asm
gcc -nostartfiles -m64 -o hello64 hello64.o -Wl,--entry="start"
```

The code compiles without errors, but when I run it I get this segmentation fault:

```
./hello64: Symbol `scanf' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation
./hello64: Symbol `printf' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation
./hello64: Symbol `exit' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Not sure what is happening. Since this is 64-bit code, I would assume that the C functions use the [System V AMD64 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), so I am calling them accordingly (first parameters in `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, `R9`). Can anybody help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: It works with 32-bit code. I am using dynamic linking specifically because shared libraries run the startup code when they are loaded.

Comment: You're building a PIE executable so the linker doesn't automatically generate a PLT for `call printf`.  Use `-no-pie` or see the linked duplicate for the NASM syntax for a PLT or `-fno-plt` style of call to dynamically linked libc.  Also, if you call your entry point `_start`, that's the default name that `ld` looks for so you don't need `-Wl,--entry=`